# Mobile Full Screen Fixed

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve a fullscreen fixed window when viewing via mobile. The problem is when viewing in a different mobile browser i'm encountering issues like for safari bottom menu covering the fixed element I want. How do I achieve this to display properly?

This is the ideal looks

[image]

But somehow when viewing in mobile safari I get this

[image]

As you can see the social container was covered by the browser navigation bar. Is there a way to fix this? Below is my html and css code

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay_inner">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Link One</li>
            <li>Link Two</li>
            <li>Link Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="social_container">
        <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Instagram</li>
            <li>Twitter</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;    
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay_inner {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
}
.social_container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: one quick fix is to make the modal scrollable, so you can scroll down to the content you want

Comment: Yeah I can do that but the actual desired is not to make it scrollable and the social_container should always be visible. and only the content/menu items will be scrollable